# 2D - Finding largest sum of different combination in Excel

Tags: excel

I have this monthly sales by item and want to find which combination gives the largest sum. Example,

```
           Feb 2020  Mar 2020 Apr 2020 May 2020
Shoes          2         2        1        0
Phone          2         3        10       1
Computer       5         7        7       10
```

The answer is 5+7+10+10=32. I need to find the largest sum for over 50 items. Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One tricky solution is as below.

```
=SUM(MAX(B2:B4),MAX(C2:C4),MAX(D2:D4),MAX(E2:E4))
```

[image]

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. Is it possible to count just once for each item, the largest possible sum in this example will become 2(mar 2020, shoes)+10(Apr 2020, Phone)+10(May 2020, computer)=22.

Comment: If it works then please accept the answer to close the thread. You can apply same trick row wise. Use this formula `=SUM(MAX(B2:E2),MAX(B3:E3),MAX(B4:E4))`

Answer (score 1):

Another option for columns:

```
=SUM(SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET(INDEX(B2:E4,1,1),,COLUMN(B2:E4)-MIN(COLUMN(B2:E4)),ROWS(B2:E4))))
```

for rows:

```
=SUM(SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET(INDEX(B2:E4,1,1),ROW(B2:E4)-MIN(ROW(B2:E4)),,,COLUMNS(B2:E4))))
```

These are array formulas so after editing confirm them by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: If item and monthly figure can only be counted once, how can I modify the formula? In the example above, let say additional item, Speakers 2,4,5,7. The maximum sum will be 2(shoes, feb2020)+4(speakers,mar2020)+10(phone, apr2020)+10(computer, may2020)=26.

Comment: @DingHouWong It looks like that the speakers have a maximum in may - 7. Why did you wrote that it is in march - 4?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=SUM(B2:B5)` and drag it using the bottom-right edge to the other cells in column to apply the same formula.

Comment: Sales figure has to be the largest of the month. Not simple sum I'm looking for. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[Thanks to](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12188861/basic)

Another option for columns:

=SUM(SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET(INDEX(B2:E4,1,1),,COLUMN(B2:E4)-MIN(COLUMN(B2:E4)),ROWS(B2:E4))))
for rows:

=SUM(SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET(INDEX(B2:E4,1,1),ROW(B2:E4)-MIN(ROW(B2:E4)),,,COLUMNS(B2:E4))))
These are array formulas so after editing confirm them by pressing ctrl + shift + enter

enter image description here