# 2D table - Finding largest possible sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this sales table. I need to find largest possible sum for 1st half of the year. Simplified example,

```
           Jan Feb  Mar Apr May Jun
Item A     $2   $3  $2  $1  $7  $5
Item B     $2   $2  $2  $2  $4  $8 
Item C     $2   $2  $2  $9  $2  $1
Item D     $1   $10 $1  $5  $4  $2
Item E     $11  $2  $3  $4  $5  $6
Item F     $2   1   $12 $2  $4  $5
```

Sales of the month and item can only be counted once. Example here, largest possible sum is $11+$10+$12+$9+$7+$8=$57. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I have already provided answer to your previous post [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64979369/5514747)

Comment: It's similar but not the same. My problem now is that each column and row can only be counted once.

Answer (score 0):

Sum of monthly column max number

In `I2`, enter formula :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET(A2:A7,0,COLUMN(B1:G1)-COLUMN(A1))))
```

[image]